# ArguementOutOfRangeException was unhandled c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, collections, listbox

In a WPF application I have some radio buttons and a listbox. The listbox displays objects from an observable collection called 'staff' when a particular radio button is pressed. I have a selectionChanged event method used to display information to a textblock when an item in the listbox is selected. When I select the radio buttons the correct items get added to the collection and displayed in the listbox but I am getting an 'ArguementOutOfRangeException was unhandled error' if I select an item in the listbox and then select a different radiobutton.

In summary, getting an error when trying to access the collection after selecting listbox item and then selecting a different radio button.

Error is occurring at second line in the code in in the event method below;

```
private void lbxDisplay_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int itemNumber = lbxDisplay.SelectedIndex;
        string itemString = staff[itemNumber].ToString();
```

Comment: Try putting some breakpoints in and see if the values are what you think they should be.  A little debugging never hurt anybody.

Comment: Will you please provide more of the code...including what happens when the radio button selection changes?

Comment: always check SelectedIndex for valid values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're changing the selection from one `RadioButton` to another, the `ListBox`'s contents are cleared, which causes the `SelectionChanged` event to be fired, and when there's nothing to select, the `SelectedIndex` goes to -1.  Then, in your `lbxDisplay_SelectionChanged` method, you try to retrieve `staff[-1]`.

Comment: Adv12, Thanks - that was the problem. I solved it using a if else to check if the listbox selected index as less than zero and if it was in the else I made lbsDisplay.SelectedIndex = 0;
            if (lbxDisplay.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                int itemNumber = lbxDisplay.SelectedIndex;
                string itemString = staff[itemNumber].ToString();
……………………………….more code}
else
{ lbsDisplay.SelectedIndex = 0;}